# Difference between residuals and idiosyncratic errors?

Tags: time-series, econometrics, residuals, terminology, error

I have a simple question. I want to know the difference between the residuals obtained from a model and idiosyncratic errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest difference is that residuals is a term used in statistics and "idiosyncratic errors" isn't.

In statistics there is a distinction between [error and residuals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors_and_residuals), where in the model

$$
y = f(x) + \varepsilon
$$

$\varepsilon$ is the *error term*, while

$$
r = y - \hat y
$$

where $\hat y$ is the fitted value, is the *residual*.

I did a quick online search and appears in publications be econometricians, like [those slides](https://statmath.wu.ac.at/%7Efruehwirth/Oekonometrie_III%20(Angewandte%20%C3%96konometrie)/Econometrics_III_teil9.pdf)

> The basic panel data model is given by:
>
> $$ y_{it} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1,it} + \beta_2 x_{2,it} + \dots +
>  \beta_K x_{K,it} + a_i + u_{it}, \qquad (18) $$
>
> with idiosyncratic errors $u_{it}$  [...]

where clearly they mean the error term. Same [here](https://scholarworks.iu.edu/dspace/bitstream/handle/2022/21957/2015-02-13_wim_mcmanus_panel_slides.pdf) where the author also has econometrics background, or discussed on [/r/econometrics](https://www.reddit.com/r/econometrics/comments/npj4ib/idiosyncratic_errors_and_fixed_effect_in_panel/).

Comment: Great explanation! If the errors in the model are allowed to follow and AR(1) process, does it mean that residuals can also follow an AR(1) process?

Comment: If $\hat y$ is a prediction, I would say $r=y-\hat y$ is a prediction error, not a residual. It would be a residual if $\hat y$ were a fitted value.

Comment: @RichardHardy yeah, corrected.